# How to create in all subfolders of a given directory subfolder with given name

Tags: bash

I have a directory structure like this in my CentOS:

```
dir1
dir2
dir3
...
```

Now, I would like to create in each `dirN` folder a sub-folder named converted. I tried with:

```
> find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir mkdir converted {} +
```

But without success. Could anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TCLSH VERSION:**

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec mkdir -p \{\}/converted \;
```

You have to escape the curly braces with "\".

**BASH VERSION:**

Fist login into BASH:

```
bash --login
```

then perform the command:

```
sudo find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec mkdir -p {}/converted  \;
```

What worked out for me.
But it also creates the folder converted on top of those directories.
Also are you in the specific folder where you want to create those sub dirs?

If not please navigate first into the folder or change the find command params like so:

```
sudo find /PATH/TO/YOUR/DIR -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec mkdir -p {}/converted  \;
```

IF you really want to stick to tclsh:

Optional:

This is just my opinion:

You should really use BASH or ZSH for your daily sysadmin/programming work.
If you want to change the $SHELL type in:

```
sudo chsh
```

Comment: unfortunately it is not working for me. I am getting multiple lines with:
mkdir: cannot create directory `/converted': Permission denied

Comment: I tested it on Bash and ZSH on Debian. It could be that the find command behaves differently on centOS. Which shell do you use?

Comment: OH permission denied: Ok try prepending sudo; edited my post.

Comment: @auL5agoi: The message OP reported indicated that it was tried to create a directory on the root level. Which is obviously wrong. sudo should be reserved to administrative tasks. This is no administrative task, so don't use sudo.

Comment: @Drago: If it tells you `/converted` you entered something wrong. It should not try to create a directory on the root (`/`) level. Make sure you enter the command line just as auL5agoi wrote it. Most importantly there must be no space(s) between `{}` and `/converted`. It must be one single entity i.e. `{}/converted`. Also make sure, that you're already in the directory containing the subdirectories when executing the `find` utility. You could also instead pass the absolute path to the base directory as the first parameter to `find`.

Comment: > echo $SHELL
/bin/tcsh
@datenwolf I entered the command exactly as in the answer and I am in the directory, containing the subdirectories. But it is not working for me

Comment: @Drago: I must admit that I'm not familiar with csh-family shells, but it could be, that tcsh is interpreting the curly braces for its own purposes, which means that `find` doesn't get them as part of its command line arguments. So you'll have to escape that part. A quick glance in the tcsh man page tells me, that you can use single quotes to escape strings from shell interpretation. So the suggested line would be `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec mkdir -p '{}/converted'  \;`

Comment: @datenwolf escaping was the key :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
bash
for i in dir*; do [ -d "$i" ] || continue; mkdir "$i"/converted; done
```

Comment: Unfortunately is not working:
> for i in dir*; do [ -d "$i" ] || continue; mkdir "$i"/converted; done
 for: No match.
 i: Undefined variable.

Comment: You need to be in bash